# How to simulate two quick clicks with htmlunit?

Tags: htmlunit

I have a submit button where the `onclick()` method returns `false` when it is clicked the second time. This way I try to handle users that try to double click the submit button.
With **htmlunit 2.3** I was able to test the correct behaviour like this:

```
public static void clickTwice( ClickableElement element ) throws IOException {
    element.click();
    element.click();
}
```

After updating to **htmlunit 2.12** the above code is not working anymore. `ClickableElement` was removed and `HtmlElement` was now `clickable`. So I changed it to:

```
public static void clickTwice( HtmlElement element ) throws IOException {
    element.click();
    element.click();
}
```

But now the result is different to **htmlunit 2.3**.

It seems that the first click invalidates the current page and shuts down the javascript engine. The second click is executed without `onclick()` being evaluated and so the second submit to the server isn't blocked.

**Question:** How can I simulate a user clicking twice a submit button on the same page with **htmlunit 2.12**?

Comment: Have you tried `dblClick()`?

Comment: `dblClick()` gives the following debug output: "dblClick() is ignored, as click() loaded a different page."

Comment: And that is actually the issue. You're getting a new page just after the first click, so the second click that is performed using an element in an old page doesn't make any sense to HtmlUnit. If that happens then I believe you're not using asynchronous javascript in the onClick. You could try to find a way to asynchronously execute the code in your onClick() but I'm pretty sure it will be a dirty workaround, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc Guillmot (commiter of htmlunit) gave me the solution to this problem:

```
public void clickTwice( final WebClient webClient, final HtmlElement clickable ) throws IOException {
    final WebConnection originalConnection = webClient.getWebConnection();

    WebConnectionWrapper wcw = new WebConnectionWrapper( originalConnection ) {
        private boolean m_requested = false;

        @Override
        public WebResponse getResponse( final WebRequest request ) throws IOException {
            if( m_requested ) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Double request!" );
            }

            m_requested = true;
            clickable.click();
            webClient.setWebConnection( originalConnection );

            return super.getResponse( request );
        }
    };
    webClient.setWebConnection( wcw );
    clickable.click();
}
```